# Android save base64 image into file on SDCARD

Tags: android

when i trying to save base64 String contains into file on `SD-CARD` i get error or my used method don't work fine;

```
File file = new File(Ketabkhan.IMAGE);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}
if (shabek.length() < 1)
    shabek = "test";
base64FileName = shabek.replace("-", "") + ".png";
fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Ketabkhan.IMAGE + "/" + base64FileName), true);
byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(tasvirData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
fos.write(decodedString);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

in this above code and and this line:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Ketabkhan.IMAGE + "/" + base64FileName), true);
```

create empty file, but after use this code instead of that:

```
fos = context.openFileOutput(Ketabkhan.IMAGE + "/" + base64FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

i get this error:

```
File /storage/emulated/0/Ketabkhan/images/test.png contains a path separator
```

permission is granted and

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    parseSelectedBookContains();
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_PERMISSION);
}
```

return true and `parseSelectedBookContains()` work correctly

Comment: Please check the documentation of `Context.openFileOutput`

Answer (score 0):

You cant use path separators in openFileOutput method. It can contain the name of your file but not path separators.
For more details refer to
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int))